# How to apply custom information on a function to show up when called in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a class that adds some functionality to my strings.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string formString(this string value)
    {
        value = value.Replace("\t", " ");
        value = value.Trim();
        return value;
    }
}
```

How can I add some explanation for the called function
[image]

similarly to what appears when .ToString() is called:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to add an [XML comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/xml-documentation-comments) above the method.

```
/// <summary>
/// Some informative description
/// </summary>
/// <returns>A description of the return value</returns>
public static string formString(this string value)
{
    value = value.Replace("\t", " ");
    value = value.Trim();
    return value;
}
```